# RPi 3 Full HD Kodi content on 4K TV

Tags: pi-3, kodi

I'm thinking about purchasing a TV with 4K resolution to connect to my Raspberry Pi 3 Kodi media player.

I understand that the RPi 3 isn't capable of playing true 4K content in a satisfactory way, but **what would happen if I connect my RPi3 Kodi to a 4K TV though HDMI**?

Would Kodi try to adapt, increasing its resolution to 4K and scale up Full HD content, or would Kodi provide the same Full HD signal as usual, while the TV would scale up the content? Or wouldn't it work at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to hook up my RPi to an ASUS 4K monitor through HDMI for testing purposes. The resolution remains at 1920x1080@60hz and the video output looks good. This also remains the highest possible resolution you can specify in the Kodi settings.